# Screen turns off and never goes back on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors

I'm not an experienced user, I need some help, please.

So my screen turns off when I open settings, and also the screen never turns on after I Suspend or Lock my computer. Ubuntu is running on a notebook with a permanently turned off screen, but I have an ultra wide screen connected through HDMI cable.

Here is what I found in the logs

> [drm:nv_drm_connector_get_modes [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm]
> [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to get mode at modeIndex 1 of
> NvKmsKapiDisplay 0x00000200
> GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

Here is some info that might be useful too:

```
$:~$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:150 memory:c3000000-c3ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:c4080000-c40fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:148 memory:c2000000-c2ffffff memory:60000000-6fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

P.S. Secure Boot is disabled in BIOS